# prometheus is not scraping the metrics from the app deployed on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have added endpoint `/metrics` in my app and
this is the config file i have written for prometheus

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config
apiVersion: v1
data:
  prometheus.yml: |-
    global:
      scrape_interval: 5s
      evaluation_interval: 5s
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'goserver'
      scheme: http
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
      bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - api_server: https://kubernets.default.svc
        role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app]
        regex: goserver
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
        target_label: k8s_pod
        action: replace
```

and below is the deployment file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: prometheus-server
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: prometheus
      image: prom/prometheus:latest
      args:
        - "-config.file=/etc/prometheus/conf/prometheus.yml"
        # Metrics are stored in an emptyDir volume which
        # exists as long as the Pod is running on that Node.
        # The data in an emptyDir volume is safe across container crashes.
        - "-storage.local.path=/prometheus"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
      volumeMounts:
        - name: prometheus-server-volume
          mountPath: /etc/prometheus/conf
        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          mountPath: /prometheus
  volumes:
    - name: prometheus-server-volume
      configMap:
        name: prometheus-config
    - name: prometheus-storage-volume
      emptyDir: {} # containers in the Pod can all read and write the same files here.
```

and this is the deployment file for the app

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
         app: goserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: goserver
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: utkarshmani1997/goserver:v1.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

I have created the service of prometheus and goserver on port 32514 and 32520 respectively of the type NodePort.
This is working fine with the minikube and **scrapes** the metrics from my app but not working with the kubeadm setup in virtual box (multinode cluster). What changes i have to make in order to get the metrics on kubernetes.
I tried to make few changes in [rbac-setup.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/rbac-setup.yml) and [prometheus-kubernetes.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml) also but it is not working.

I am accessing the browser by ssh -NL 1234:localhost:32514 from outside the cluster,because vagrant box does not have ubuntu desktop ui.

Comment: are you able to curl the go app `/metrics` endpoint from the node running Prometheus?

Comment: @Gavin yes on doing curl it's giving the custom metrics scrapped.

Comment: the problem is the 'goserver' pod's status is down and gives  "can't skip unknown wire type 7 for io_prometheus_client.MetricFamily" error

Comment: Have a look at - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-developers/vhHcNbSqd14, seems like a content format issue - Prometheus is expecting/configured to read via protobuf, but the output format is actually Text.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue,actually the issue was related to rbac. I didn't added the serviceAccountName in deployment file. Now it is working fine with the new change.